# Windows XP CPU usage at 100% with all processes showing zero

Tags: windows-xp, cpu

I use Windows XP regularly. My Task Manager shows 100% USAGE, however, all processes are at zero. Task Manager shows zero and, system idle is at zero.

Comment: Have you checked the box for "Show processes from all users" on the processes tab? Also, on the Performance tab, turn on Show kernel Times from the View menu. What does the red line show?

Answer (score 4):

Something is using your CPU and is hidden from Task Manager.

Scan for malware, using [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.com/) and [SuperAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If no Malware, use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) as a task Manager replacement to find out what is using CPU

Comment: I should have added it to your answer.